# Undefined offset 1 in my yii2 site

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
Failed to prepare SQL: INSERT INTO `form` (`name`, `email`, `age`, `height`, `weight`, `city`, `techies`, `english_level`, `images`) VALUES (:qp0, :qp1, :qp2, :qp3, :qp4, :qp5, :qp6, :qp7, :qp8)
```

I have that error when trying to put data from form to my yii2 database. I created model for that purpose, created action in my controller and view with ActiveForm to send data. Now I just need to get data from that form and put that into my db.
Error occur in this line:

```
if (($loaded = $Form->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) && $Form->save())
```

it's one line for my controller action:

```
public function actionForm()
{
    $Form = new Form();
    if(!$Form->validate()){
        var_dump("fuck");
    }
    if (($loaded = $Form->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) && $Form->save()) {
                return 'ok';
    }elseif($loaded){
 var_dump($Form->getErrors());
 }

    return $this->render('form',array(
       'Form' => $Form,
    ));
}
```

my requests data:

```
$_GET = [
    'r' => 'site/form',
];

$_POST = [
    '_csrf' => 'MGhXNV82cTdkBTFPC3k4VAVRZUEoBDxZUi4cRSpnAUZaMTxxbwZEBQ==',
    'Form' => [
        'name' => 'Rost',
        'email' => 'prozrostl@gmail.com',
        'age' => '22',
        'height' => '12',
        'weight' => '1212',
        'city' => '1212',
        'techies' => 'yes_camera',
        'english_level' => 'starter',
        'images' => [
            '',
        ],
    ],
];

$_FILES = [
    'Form' => [
        'name' => [
            'images' => [
                'user.png',
            ],
        ],
        'type' => [
            'images' => [
                'image/png',
            ],
        ],
        'tmp_name' => [
            'images' => [
                'W:\\XAMPP\\tmp\\php649A.tmp',
            ],
        ],
        'error' => [
            'images' => [
                0,
            ],
        ],
        'size' => [
            'images' => [
                445,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

and I have model generated through gii.

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "form".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $email
 * @property integer $age
 * @property integer $height
 * @property integer $weight
 * @property string $city
 * @property string $techies
 * @property string $english_level
 * @property string $images
 * @property resource $photo_1
 * @property resource $photo_2
 * @property resource $photo_3
 * @property resource $photo_4
 * @property resource $photo_5
 */
class Form extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'form';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'email', 'age', 'height', 'weight', 'city', 'techies', 'english_level'], 'required'],
            [['name', 'email', 'city', 'techies', 'english_level'], 'string'],
            [['images', 'photo_1', 'photo_2', 'photo_3', 'photo_4', 'photo_5'], 'file'],
            [['age', 'height', 'weight'], 'integer'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'age' => 'Age',
            'height' => 'Height',
            'weight' => 'Weight',
            'city' => 'City',
            'techies' => 'Techies',
            'english_level' => 'English Level',
            'photo_1' => 'Photo 1',
            'photo_2' => 'Photo 2',
            'photo_3' => 'Photo 3',
            'photo_4' => 'Photo 4',
            'photo_5' => 'Photo 5',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I see your $_POST['images'] key is the array and there is `images` column in the query - are you trying to save empty array there or is there any processing for this column involved?

Comment: It is better to save images at some location in your server, example :- @frontend/web/images  and save only image names in the database columns. retrieving such a Blob with hit your performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you send the images value in the post is an array. You have to json encode the value before you save it to the database.

In your Form model override the load function:

```
public function load($data, $formName = null)
    {
        $scope = $formName === null ? $this->formName() : $formName;
        if($scope) {
            $data[$scope]['images'] = \yii\helpers\Json::encode($data[$scope]['images']);
        }
        else {
            $data['images'] = \yii\helpers\Json::encode($data['images']);
        }
        return parent::load($data, $formName); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
```